# Launch an OS X app with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to open an application. How do I do that? I tried adding a service, but services can't be bound to this combination for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [BetterTouchTools](http://www.boastr.de/)... its FREE!

The "Keyboard" tab in this application allows you to set any keyboard keys to "Open Application / File / Script" as well as many other useful things.

BetterTouchTools main purpose is to customize multi-touch devices... which is awesome! However, it works great for keyboard shortcuts as well. You may want to consider using multi-touch along with keyboard shortcuts. I find it to be very useful.

The picture below shows just a few of the things your keyboard shortcuts can do. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Third party applications that support assigning shortcuts to applications:

- [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/)
- [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/)
- [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de)
- [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/)
- [iKey](http://plumamazing.com/mac/ikey/)
- [Keyboard Cowboy](http://zenangst.com/app/keyboardcowboy)
- [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)
- [Keymando](http://keymando.com/)
- [Launch it!](http://launchitapp.com/)
- [NuKit](http://nulana.com/nukit)
- [Quickeys](http://startly.com/products/quickeys/mac/4/)
- [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com)
- [Shortcuts](http://nulana.com/shortcuts)
- [Spark](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php)
- [Twitch](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/twitch/id414379973?mt=12)

I use Alfred, and I've used [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) to convert single keys to ⌃⌥⇧⌘ and ⌃⌥⌘.

[image]

You could also assign shortcuts to shell commands like `open -a iTunes`. AppleScripts like this are blocked until the application finishes opening, so they seem to take longer if they are run with FastScripts:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    reopen
    activate
end tell
```

You could also create Automator services:

[image]

There's a bug on 10.7 and 10.8 where the shortcuts for Automator services don't always work until you have hovered over the services menu from the menu bar. There's also a short delay before they are run, and they aren't available in applications that don't have a [services menu](https://superuser.com/questions/432969/services-keyboard-shortcuts-dont-work-for-some-mac-apps).

Answer (score 2):

Assign not a *Service* keyboard shortcut, but a custom *Application* shortcut that works in *All applications*, and enter your service name as the name of the menu entry.