# Replacement For Mac OS X Dock

Tags: macos, dock

I have been using Mac OS X Loin since two months and feel that I can't tweak the Dock much. 
For Example, I am unable to stretch the Dock to 100% width of the screen.

My Idea is something similar to windows classic task bar (or gnome2 panel). Do anyone of use is aware any app with such options? If not then is there something else you prefer over Mac OS X Dock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many OS X users just keep the Dock hidden and ignore it most of the time. You can use ⌘⇥ to switch between active applications and quit them. Other apps can be opened with Spotlight or third party launchers like [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/index.html) or [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/). (Or [keyboard shortcuts](https://superuser.com/questions/266829/launch-an-os-x-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/309144#309144).)

There are a few graphical launchers and Dock replacement apps, but none have been that popular. (See [osx.iusethis.com/tag/dock](http://osx.iusethis.com/tag/dock).) There was one app that aimed at providing something like the Windows task bar for OS X, Fantastik, but [its website has been taken offline](http://web.archive.org/web/20110207133431/http://docklandsoft.com/).

Comment: Spotlight Works Great for me. I think hiding+minimizing dock w/o a replacement would be a bad idea because then I wont be able to get back minimised windows (or can I? not sure.) Alternatively I have stuffed the dock with frequently used applications so that Its width will go beyond 95% of screen size and it go more skinny. Then I aligned it to the left. This setup looks decent, everything is now within a single click away or Spotlight does the stuff. Will stick to this setup until I find something more decent :)

Comment: You don't really need to minimize windows that often (or at all). Just use ⌘H to hide applications and ⌘\` to cycle between windows in the active app... But one way to unminimize windows without the Dock would be to use [Witch.app](http://manytricks.com/witch/). (A replacement for the cmd-tab application switcher.)

Comment: Oh. I wasnt aware of ⌘H. Now I can go dockless :)