# Hotkey to Focus App in Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion, shortcuts, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launch an OS X app with a keyboard shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/266829/launch-an-os-x-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut)

While developing, I have found that I am Command-Tabbing between 9 or so applications. It'd be great to set hotkeys to immediately focus on the most used applications like Chrome or Vim. This would be much faster.

I tried looking at System Preferences, Alfred hotkeys as suggested from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788565/keyboard-shortcut-to-focus-on-an-app-in-mac-os.

I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Thank you!

Comment: A great way to learn Cocoa development is to write your own simple Hot Key app:  http://i.imgur.com/DsVV3.png

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks for the suggestion. I'm interested and have played with Cocoa before. Do you have any tips on how to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since swapping between desktops is so easy in Lion, would you consider setting up a separate desktop for your high-use applications? This could be a functional alternative.

A swipe or two will have you where you need to be.